# Does Dockerfile EXPOSE command support ${bash//search/replace}?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Trying to do this

```
EXPOSE ${PORTS//,/ }
```

results on this

```
ERROR: Service 'test' failed to build: failed to process "${PORTS//,/": missing ':' in substitution
```

Can anyone tell why?

**EDIT**

PORTS will receive a value like 80,8080,...

And the EXPOSE command will  be like `EXPOSE 80 8080 ...`

**To reporduce**

`./docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  test:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - PORTS=80,443,8080
```

`./Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine:latest

ARG PORTS=80

EXPOSE ${PORTS//,/ }
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: expose ports on a list separated by ','

Comment: As per Docker Docks, Expose takes one port or port/protocol https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Comment: you can map the container to multiple ports when you start it up then. For example if you exposed 8080. you can do -p 80:8080 -p 8080:8080 -p 7777:8080 and this way you can access your container on all those ports.

Comment: ...since you can pick an arbitrary host port in the way @RomanMik describes, the port you `EXPOSE` is almost always fixed.  You can pick any port number you want but something that’s natural for your protocol/language/framework is common.

Comment: @RomanMik I believe your interpretation for this command is wrong...the descriptions says `EXPOSE <port> [<port>/<protocol>...]` with the `...` I believe they mean that can be a list

Comment: @DavidMaze it's possible to define an `ARG` for the ports to be exposed and use it later with `EXPOSE`...I do this every time :)

Comment: I never had the case to do that, but I'm curious now. I'll do a test and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

To `EXPOSE` a dynamic port that you want to set at the container creation you can do this

`Dockerfile`

```
...
ARG PORT
EXPOSE $PORT
```

Run

`docker run -e PORT=5000 container:tag`